# How to add a Slack reaction to a send_card

Tags: python, errbot

I have an Errbot function that sends a Slack card.  How do I then add a reaction to the card instead of the original message(msg) that was received?

```
@botcmd
def example(self, msg):
    self.send_card(title='Test',
            body='test123',
            thumbnail=' ',
            image=' ',
            link=' ',
            color='green',
            in_reply_to=msg)
    self._bot.add_reaction(card_msg??, 'grey_question')
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

send_card [does not return to you the message it sends](https://github.com/errbotio/errbot/blob/bec91d613b0fb123af4f3b305b36d3849705eed4/errbot/core.py#L189) which means you will have to do something to get the message info of the card you sent.

One option would be to trigger a [callback for all messages](http://errbot.io/en/latest/user_guide/plugin_development/messaging.html#trigger-a-callback-with-every-message-received) in your plugin, inspect the message, and add your reaction there:

Another option could be to use the [slack backend api call](http://errbot.io/en/latest/errbot.backends.slack.html#errbot.backends.slack.SlackBackend.api_call) method to search for your message and add the reaction that way.